# Rails Way - Generating New Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So, I have a many-to-many relationship between Users and Exams, using a Permissions as the middle table.

I want to create a table for the administrator to grant different levels of access to different tests.

So, is there a better way to create new Permission records than to loop through all the exams that aren't already tied to this user and create a new permission?

Note, some or all of the exams may already be tied to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :exams, through: :permissions
end

class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :users, through: :permissions
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :exam
end
```

You can just do something like this:

```
user = User.find(1)
if user.exams.where(id:foo).length==0
  Permission.create(user_id:1, exam_id0:foo, access_level:bar)
else
  user.permissions.where(exam_id:foo).first.update_attribute(:access_level,bar)
end
```

It will join the tables and determine whether or not the permission already exists very quickly, assuming you built the relationship normally (with indices on `user_id` and `exam_id` in permissions).